# Convert a dataframe to a character array?

Tags: r

I am trying to convert a dataframe to a character array in R.

- THIS WORKS BUT THE TEXT FILE ONLY CONTAINS LIKE 83 RECORDS

  ```
  data <- readLines("https://www.r-bloggers.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/vent.txt")
  df <- data.frame(data)
  textdata <- df[df$data, ]
  ```
- THIS DOES NOT WORK..MAYBE BECAUSE IT HAS 3k RECORDS?

  ```
  trump_posts <- read.csv(file="C:\\Users\\TAFer\\Documents\\R\\TrumpFBStatus1.csv", 
                          sep = ",", stringsAsFactors = TRUE)
  trump_text <- trump_posts[trump_posts$Facebook.Status, ]
  ```

All I know is I have a dataframe called trump posts. The frame has a single column called Facebook.Status. I just wanted to turn it into a character array so I can run an analysis on it.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If `Facebook.Status` is a character vector you can directly perform your analysis on it.

Or you can try:

`trump_text <- as.character(trump_posts$Facebook.Status)`

Answer (score 0):

I think you are somehow confusing `data.frame` syntax with `data.table` syntax. For DF, you'd reference vector as `df$col`. However, for DT it is somewhat similar to what you wrote `dt[,col]` or `dt[,dt$col]`. Also, if you want a character vector right away, set  `stringsAsFactors = F` in your `read.csv`. Otherwise you'll need extra conversion, for example, `dt[,as.character(col)]` or `as.character(df$col)`.

And on a side note, size of vector is almost never an issue, unless you hit the limits of your hardware.